# AttributeError: 'ShaderNodeTree' object has no attribute 'active_output'

Tags: python

I've working on "private" exporter and it has some issues like the topic. The addon perfectly working inside latest Blender 3.6.5 but did not worked with 4.0a and 4.1a. Here the part of codes:

```python
def getOutputNode(material):
    node = None
    if material.use_nodes and material.cout.use_nodes and material.node_tree:
        node_tree = material.node_tree
        if node_tree.active_output != -1 and node_tree.nodes[node_tree.active_output].bl_idname == "COutputNode":
            node = node_tree.nodes[node_tree.active_output]
        if not node:
            for n in node_tree.nodes:
                if n.bl_idname == "COutputNode" and n.is_active_output:
                    node = n
    return node

def findCOutputNode(material):
    node = None
    if material.node_tree:
        node_tree = material.node_tree
        if node_tree.active_output != -1 and \
            node_tree.nodes[node_tree.active_output].bl_idname == "COutputNode":
            node = node_tree.nodes[node_tree.active_output]
        if not node:
            for n in node_tree.nodes:
                if n.bl_idname == "COutputNode":
                    node = n
    return node
```

and here that error:

```
    if node_tree.active_output != -1 and node_tree.nodes[node_tree.active_output].bl_idname == "COutputNode":
```

`AttributeError: 'ShaderNodeTree' object has no attribute 'active_output'`

Answer (score 2):

The Blender Node Tree structure has changed in 4.0. So, no longer are inputs or outputs accessed through `NodeTree.inputs` or `NodeTree.outputs` but by iterating over `NodeTree.interface.items_tree`. Getting the **active_item** can be found through `NodeTree.interface.active` but it is not targeted to inputs or outputs. It will be harder to get the active input or output due to the API changes.
For more detail, visit [4.0 Node Group Python API](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API#:%7E:text=Node%20Groups,to%20NodeTree.interface)

```
    for item in tree.interface.items_tree:
        if item.item_type == 'SOCKET':
            if item.in_out == 'INPUT':
                ...
            elif item.in_out == 'OUTPUT':
```

Comment: Where am I must change this lines? ' for item in tree.interface.items_tree:
        if item.item_type == 'SOCKET':
            if item.in_out == 'INPUT':
                ...
            elif item.in_out == 'OUTPUT': '

Comment: Substitute `tree` in `tree.interface.items_tree` with the tree you are working on.  You can make a function to find the output closest to the active item if the active item is not an output.

Comment: I'm a bit stumped that the new API is so much more complicated than the previous one... I understand that it opens up a lot of possibilites UI wise to have subpanels in the in/outputs but it makes the entry barrier for newbies much higher...

Comment: I totally agree with you. For panels, they should have just added a 'Panels' ui list and make them accessible through `tree.inputs`, `tree.outputs`, or `tree.panels`. However, I'm not a Dev and they may have better reasons to do it the way they did it,

Comment: Guys, please, help me! I don't understand which am I must to do and which lines are need to change?